# How to save the data in an url using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the content to pass in the below mentioned url.

post parameters are :
Summary
 Desc 
Type 
Acc_cr

Explanation: Desc:"As a"+whoTextField.text +"\n I want"+whatTextView.text+"\n so that"+outputTextField.text

Type:"story"

Post url is http://172.25.183.183:8080/jiraservice/rest/create/and

Comment: What are `Summary` and `Acc_r`?

Comment: Those are just keys...

Comment: We can pass dummy data